# В датафрейм Pandas внести значения строк, выровненных по одному из столбцов

Tags: python, pandas

У меня таблица, где 2 расчета косинусов: второй идет по точкам с интервалом, в 2 раза более частым, чем первый.

Таким образом, в некоторых точках все значения совпадают, в других нет.

Требуется: разнести строки. Там, где значения совпадают - все значения ставим в одну строку, где не совпадают - значения ставим на новую строку.

На выходе должно быть так:

```
i   x_i   cos(x_i)  x_j   cos(x_j)
0   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
1                   0.157   0.987
2   0.314   0.309   0.314   0.309
3                   0.471   0.891
```

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe['i'] = pd.Series([0.00, 0.314, 0.628, 0.942])
dataframe['cos(x_i)'] = pd.Series([0.000, 0.309, 0.587, 0.809])
dataframe['j'] = pd.Series([0.00, 0.157, 0.314, 0.471])
dataframe['cos(x_j)'] = pd.Series([0.000, 0.987, 0.309, 0.891])

for col in dataframe:
    if dataframe.iloc['i'] == dataframe.iloc['j']:
        # в датафрейм вносим всю строку
    else:
        # спускаемся на строку ниже
        # в датафрейм вносим ячейки столбцов 'j' и 'cos(x_j)'
```

Comment: датафрейм задан странно, через сеты. непонятно, где у вас "все значения " совпадают. не известно, что  такое setka. в общем, подготовьте исходный пример в воспроизводимом виде и на нем покажите, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Да, без примеров непонятно. Тем более что таблица это таблица, в ней нельзя произвольно менять число столбцов в разных строках. Приведите пример, что вы хотите получить из этой таблицы на выходе.

Comment: Да у вас цикл в целом не рабочий, оставьте как есть, не тратьте время на исправления, лучше пример напишите

Comment: @strawdog, в приводимых значениях фактически совпадение идет по `0.000` и `0.314`. Касательно `setka` - по ошибке вышла из моего исходного кода: исправил, убрав

Comment: А куда делись строки где `i` равно 0.628, 0.942? Или нас интересует только `j` и мы на него ориентируемся только, а `i` нам интересно только в плане совпадения или нет с `j`? Но в любом случае пустые ячейки сделать нельзя, можно туда `NA` например прописать, так пойдёт?

Comment: @CrazyElf, да пустые значения обозначенные как `NaN` подойдут. Касательно прочих значений `i`, в данном случае непринципиально. На реальном примере у меня численный ряд, причем значений `i` в 2 раза меньше, чем значений `j`. На этом я и споткнулся. Если ничего циклом не изменить, то там путаница: в одной строке косинусы для значения `i=0.314` и значения `j=0.157`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам через `merge`, фактически это `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, говоря языком `SQL`. Пришлось потом колонки местами переставить только, ну и отфильтровать `NA` в `j`:

```py
df = pd.merge(dataframe[['j', 'cos(x_j)']], dataframe[['i', 'cos(x_i)']], 
              how='outer', left_on='j', right_on='i')
df = df[['i', 'cos(x_i)', 'j', 'cos(x_j)']]
df = df[~df['j'].isna()]
df
```

| index | i | cos(x_i) | j | cos(x_j) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | 0.157 | 0.987 |
| 2 | 0.314 | 0.309 | 0.314 | 0.309 |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | 0.471 | 0.891 |

А циклы лучше с `Pandas` никогда не использовать - это медленно и вообще неправильно.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что дает тильда?

Comment: Тильда даёт отрицание условия :)